# Rotating digits of an integer

Tags: perl, integer

How do I rotate the digits of integer? Here are sample inputs and Outputs:

## Sample Input

12345
10901

## Sample Output

51234
11090

Comment: Do you want to rotate them the same way all the time or randomly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$x = chop($x) . $x;
```

or

```
$x = substr("$x$x",length($x)-1,length($x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

for my $x (qw(12345 10901)) {
    my $r = substr($x, -1, 1) . substr($x, 0, -1);
    print "$r\n";
}
```

Output:

```
51234
11090
```